# Draw a line in a pm3d map

Tags: gnuplot, density-plot

I have a[image: density map] and I want to overplot on it a [image: line].

I define the line as a 3d line with constant height and I thought that with this method I have the possibility to overplot them one to another but, unfortunately, I failed.
I realized in fact that the density map routine in gnuplot take the points of the line too.

This is my script:

```
reset

#set terminal pngcairo size 800,500 enhanced font 'Verdana,14'
#set output "map.png"
set title 'Map'


m_star=1.054
m_1=0.0093866
m_3=0.0078635

fact1 = (m_star+m_1)**0.5
fact2 = (m_star+m_3)**0.5

set pm3d map interpolate 1,1
set xrange [50.22:52.27]
set yrange [30.29:31.17]

splot "file.txt" u (fact1)*(($1)**(-1.5)):(fact2)*(($2)**(-1.5)):6 notitle ,\
      "line.txt" notitle
```

And here the two files: [line](http://www.filedropper.com/line_1) and [density map](http://www.filedropper.com/file_282).

It is possible to overplot them, in gnuplot?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `set pm3d`, this style is used for all plots unless you explicitely specify a different plotting style. So you must use

```
splot "file.txt" u (fact1)*(($1)**(-1.5)):(fact2)*(($2)**(-1.5)):6 ,\
      "line.txt" with lines
```

in order to plot `line.txt` as line:

[image]