# How to plot discrete points on top of pm3d map in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

So I am using a pm3d map to plot a data file with 3 columns x, y, z. The final plot shows some region in 2d and I have another data file x, y which are discrete coordinates of some of the points on the boundary of the region. I want to plot these points on top of a plot generated by pm3d map. If I simply try replot after plotting pm3d map, it doesn't show those points in the plot. Can anybody kindly tell me how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here is the minimal example. The data file is something like this:

```
0.00      -0.50                4
0.00      -0.25                4
0.00       0.00                4
0.00       0.25                4
0.00       0.50                4

0.25      -0.50               1
0.25      -0.25               1
0.25       0.00               1
0.25       0.25               1
0.25       0.50               1

0.50      -0.50               0
0.50      -0.25               0
0.50       0.00               0
0.50       0.25               0
0.50       0.50               0

0.75      -0.50               0
0.75      -0.25               0
0.75       0.00               0
0.75       0.25               0
0.75       0.50               0

1.00      -0.50                3
1.00      -0.25                4
1.00       0.00                4
1.00       0.25                5
1.00       0.50                5
```

I am plotting this by following commands:

```
set pm3d map
set pm3d corners2color c1
spl 'file.dat'
```

I also have another file border.dat which contains discrete points like this:

```
0.00      -0.25
0.25       0.25
1.00       0.00
```

Now I want to plot the points (x and y coordinates) of the points given in this file on top of the plot that pm3d map (I am not using with pm3d; it's pm3d map!) generates for file.dat.

How can I achieve this? 
Thank you

Comment: Please show a minimal example, which shows what you are doing exactly, and which allows us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27206702/2174266), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13110402/2174266)

Comment: @Christoph: I thought that question was self-evident. Sorry for that. Now I have added a minimal example. Please see if you could help me with this. Thanks

Comment: @vagoberto: Thanks but I already saw this link before asking the question. The problem is that I am using pm3d map to plot my original plot and not just pm3d. Thus, this generates actually a 2d plot and hence the method described in the answer does not work for me.

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar Indeed the second link worked for me: `set pm3d map; spl 'file.dat', 'points.dat' using 1:2:(0) with lines`. i.e. you need to specify a z-coordinate (equal to cero) with the using modifier.

Comment: @vagoberto: Oh! Thanks a lot! Worked! I didn't know that something like 1:2:(0) is possible. Can you add this as an answer so that I could accept it?